# How to develop several Swift Package Manager packages in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I am developing the main app and a library (open source, forked but will go back into main repository) used by the app at the same time. I want to use Swift Package Manager and Xcode at the same time. What is the best setup in order to use the best of both worlds? Can I develop both in one workspace?

Comment: I realised that one can define local packages via path. Not sure how I could have overseen that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll describe the approach I've used before. I'm assuming you have the Swift Package available as source code in a folder, e.g. cloned using Git.

1. Open your main app project
2. Drag the root folder of the Swift Package onto your Xcode project
3. Open the project overview, select your app target, and under *"Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content"*, add your library
4. Import the library in any Swift file where you depend on it

This will resolve and fetch all dependencies and still allow you to change source code in the library on the fly if you need to.

Comment: Do you drag the folder? Or generate package of library and drag that one?.

Comment: Just drag the root folder of the library you want to add. That is, the folder that contains your `Package.swift` file and your `Sources/` and `Tests/` directories.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems. In my Xcode project I create two packages. They're local for now but might be moved to independent packages later. Package 1 depends on Package 2. I followed Alain Stulz's recommendation and still got "missing dependencies" errors. Then I physically deleted the "import ..." line and re-entered it, letting Xcode suggest a package name. At that point, it worked. Maybe that cut/re-enter triggered some behind-the-scenes update.

Update... This sort of works but I think because I end up doing two builds. I do a clean and then build/run my app. The build fails because the referenced dependency can't be found. I just click again on run and the build is successful. I suspect I've not set up some build dependency between Package 1 and 2.

Another update... I can't seem to have more than one distinct package defined in the project. Where the package is local; i.e., I'm writing the code now and might upload it to git later for use with SPM. What I can do is create one package and have its package.swift file define two libraries in the products section. I then define multiple targets where one might have dependencies on the other.

Not being able to add more than one top-level package under my packages directory doesn't make sense to me because the project already added a RealityKitContent package.

Version 15.3 (15E204a)